# Choosing the 3 largest numbers and adding them together

Tags: c

I think my logic is sound...but what i'm trying to do is when some one selects 4 dice it takes the highest 3 numbers and adds them together. the little section below where it randomly selects 4 dice.

see code below ( excuse the bad commenting )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>





int Roll_Dice(void)
{
setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IONBF, 0);
int dice1 = 0;
int dice2 = 0;
int dice3 = 0;
int dice4 = 0;
int dice_roll= 0;
int sides;
int dice;
int min;

srand(time(NULL));
{
rollagain:   
printf("how many sides of the dice are there? (maximum 12)");
scanf ("%d", &sides);

choosedice:
printf("how many dice are there? (maximum 4)\n");
scanf ("%d", &dice);

if (sides > 12)
    {
        printf("this is not a valid input, must be 12 or less\n ");

        goto rollagain;
       } else { 
            if (dice == 1){
    dice1 = (rand() % sides) + 1;
    dice_roll = dice1;
} else {
    if (dice == 2){
            dice1 = (rand() % sides) + 1;
            dice2 = (rand() % sides) + 1;
            dice_roll = dice1 + dice2;
        } else {
        if (dice == 3){
            dice1 = (rand() % sides) + 1;
            dice2 = (rand() % sides) + 1;
            dice3 = (rand() % sides) + 1;
            dice_roll = dice1 + dice2 + dice3;
            } else {
                if (dice == 4){
            dice1 = (rand() % sides) + 1;
            dice2 = (rand() % sides) + 1;
            dice3 = (rand() % sides) + 1;
            dice4 = (rand() % sides) + 1;
                } /* dice_roll = dice1 + dice2 + dice3 + dice4; */
            min = dice1;
            if ((dice2 < min)){ //this is the section where it should choose the highest 3 numbers. but i think i have nested it incorrectly...
                min == dice2;
                         {
                            if (dice3 < min)
                            min == dice3;
                        else {
                            if (dice4 < min)
                            min == dice4;
                        }
                        }
                dice_roll = dice1 + dice2 + dice3 + dice4 - min;


            } else {
                    if (dice > 4) {
                        printf ("The amount of dice must be 4 or Less, try Again\n");
                        goto choosedice;
                    }

            }

            }
        }
}
printf("the number you rolled was %d \n", dice_roll);
return dice_roll;
}
}

}
```

I think i am nesting it incorrectly... or putting it in the wrong spot. like i said i think my logic on how i am doing it is okay, but it's finding the correct place. Could anyone spot anything?

i do realise i use an if statement and then another if statement within that one... but i can't accomplish it with an else statement in there.

Would it also be feasible to put the code for selecting the highest 3 numbers in it's own function, and then calling that function within the if statement?

thanks for your input.

Comment: You are using `goto` the way that makes some programmers avoid it completely.

Comment: use while() loops, not goto.  always check the returned value from scanf() to assure the input/conversion operation was successful,  the if statements for the number of dice would be much clearer if a switch() were used.  do not use tabs in source code, use spaces.  then the posted code would be readable.

Comment: This is an error `min == dice2;` you want `min = dice2;` or `if (min == dice2){...}`

Comment: Thanks, yeah i think i might change to using a switch statement. haven't programmed in years so still getting back into it. goto was a quick fix to get the basics working. @user3629249

Comment: @BarmakShemirani noted. and changed, dunno why i did that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace all of the nested `if` statements with a simple `for` loop.

```
int rollDice(void)
{
    int sides = getNumber("how many sides of the dice are there? (maximum 12)", 12);
    int dice  = getNumber("how many dice are there? (maximum 4)", 4);

    int min = 1000;
    int roll = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dice; i++)
    {
        int value = rand() % sides + 1;
        if (value < min)
            min = value;
        roll += value;
    }
    if (dice == 4)
        roll -= min;

    return roll;
}
```

User input can be handled in a subroutine, which doesn't return until the user enters a valid number.

```
int getNumber(char *prompt, int max)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("%s: ", prompt);

        if (scanf("%d", &result) != 1)
            exit(1);

        if (result >= 1 && result <= max)
            break;

        printf("this is not a valid input, must be %d or less\n", max);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And `srand` should only be called once, typically at the beginning of `main`

```
int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (;;)
    {
        int roll = rollDice();
        printf("the number you rolled was %d\n", roll);
    }
}
```

Comment: okay awesome, i understand 95% of what is going on there. so Getnumber is the function that determines if the input is valid or not?
and diceroll rolls the number of random numbers up until the value specified at input. this makes my code seems very complicated, thank you!